# How can I enable nginx on nixos for localhost only?

Tags: firewall, nginx, nixos

I run nginx on my local machine to dispatch to various internal applications that I use quite a lot. nginx makes it easy for me to give the applications easy local aliases.

The problem is that the applications serve up very sensitive information, and so I would like to *not* have nginx listening on any of my public interfaces.

My configuration blocks in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` look like this:

```
  networking.firewall = {
    enable = true;
    # allowedTCPPorts = [ 8081 ];
  };

  services.nginx = {
    enable = true;
    recommendedProxySettings = true;
    recommendedTlsSettings = true;
    virtualHosts."localhost" = {
      locations."/wiki".proxyPass = "http://localhost:8000";
      locations."/weblog".proxyPass = "http://localhost:3001";
    };
  };
```

So, the question becomes, how can I firewall port 80?

Comment: You won't need to firewall port 80 if the service is only running on localhost

Comment: I've already verified that nginx is available on port 80 and happily routes connections from the outside to the inside services. That's what I want to prevent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that while nginx will listen to all interfaces, enabling nginx does not actually open up the port on the firewall.

In my original test, I opened the firewall port, then accessed the service from a remote machine. This was my control test to verify that the service was truly accessible. Then I closed the firewall port. The service remained accessible, but only to that browser on that computer. Future tests showed that as soon as I closed the port, other browsers could not access the service, and that original browser eventually lost access, too.

Comment: Ooooooh. Yeah, that really messed up your test. There's a feature in iptables that automatically accepts packets which are related to a previously-accepted packet. So that's probably what happened with your first browser.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, there's no NixOS configuration option to set the ngix listen port. But you can add a partial ngix configuration verbatim to *configuration.nix* using the `appendHttpConfig` option. Something like this:

```
  services.nginx = {
    enable = true;
    recommendedProxySettings = true;
    recommendedTlsSettings = true;
    virtualHosts."localhost" = {
      locations."/wiki".proxyPass = "http://localhost:8000";
      locations."/weblog".proxyPass = "http://localhost:3001";
    };

    appendHttpConfig = "listen 127.0.0.1:80";
  };
```